# Specifying field serialization priority in an HTML multipart upload form

Tags: html, file-upload

I have a file upload form which needs to have certain fields created in the multipart request before other fields. It works great if I order my form like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype"multipart/form-data" action="/upload/">
    <input type="text" name="newFileName">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

However, if I change the order of my form so that the `newFieldName` field comes *after* the `file` field, things break, as `newFieldName` needs to be parsed first by my upload handler. Is there a way to specify priority as for which fields get serialized in which order?

Comment: what do you mean "break"?

Comment: I don't think you can but what's the problem with what you have? Just use css to change the look.